# How to know whether a mail was sent or saved, while displayed?

Tags: email, delphi, outlook, mapi, outlook-redemption

**Initial situation**

- creating an `IRDOMail` in drafts, then modifying and saving it
- displaying it modal via `IRDOMail.Display`
- the user then edits the mail and sends, saves or closes it
- then using `NameSpace.SendAndRecive` to potentially initiate immediate delivery of all undelivered messages submitted in the current session
- trying to figure out wether the mail was actually sent or just saved

**Problem**

- `IRDOMail.Sent`, aswell as `IRDOMail.Submitted` are always false, altough the mail was sent and recieved

**Question besides that**

- what's the difference between `IRDOMail.Sent` and `IRDOMail.Submitted`?

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that the draft message that you display is physically different from the message in the Sent Items folder - the Sent property cannot be changed if the message has already been saved, Outlook creates a new message in the Sent Items folder.

After a message is sent, the only valid operation is releasing your reference to it, you should not be checking any of its properties.

To check if a message is sent, use the `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Is there any way to check if the new mail in the Sent Items folder originates from the displayed Draft message?

Comment: You'd need to track it somehow, by the subject, search key, etc.